# React Native flatlist conditional rendering

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have the following flat list in react native with the following
items.

key
name
type

Now i also have the following renderItem function that is used to render
the elements of the flatlist.

```
 renderItem={({ item }) => (
     <View>
     <View style={styles.navBarLeftButton}>
     <Avatar
     medium
     rounded
     source={{uri:item.name}}
     activeOpacity={0.7}
    onPress={() => console.log(this.state.data)}
    />
  <Text style={styles.textbutton}>{item.type}</Text>
  <Text>{item.description}</Text>
  <Text>{item.request} <Emoji name={item.request} style={{fontSize: 15}} /> 
 <Emoji name="pray" style={{fontSize: 15}} /></Text>
 </View>
 </View>
  )}
```

I want to render a different render function base on the item key of the flatlist
Is there away i can do conditional rendering with react native flatlist base 
on key?

Answer (score 5):

The `renderItem` prop for Flatlist can accept 2 arguments, the second being index, so you can do something like

```
renderItem={({ item, index })=>{
    if(index = 0){
        //do something
    }
}}
```

Then just throw in a switch or some if statements and you can render conditionally.

Comment: Nerdragen is there any code example that you could provide ?

Comment: the renderItem method is not accepting any conditional if statements

Comment: I am targetting  item value so it should be item.value in the if statement however when I do that it’s throwing a error regarding the if statement

Comment: In the if statement, just change the index part to a property of item.

Comment: I have if({item.value}){//do something} but still doesnt work. Have you tired ?

Comment: Graig, I'm just giving you pseudocode, you have to figure it out yourself. item.value is a value that you need to replace to further define the condition.

Answer (score 4):

> Based on 'theme' values in variable DATA (as keys) FlatList renderItem prop is conditionally accepting different Views/Components returned by separate functions

```
<FlatList
  data={DATA}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
  if (item.theme === 1) {
    return this.renderTheme1({ item });
  }
    return this.renderTheme2({ item });
  }}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

Comment: Hello krishnakumar, can you add a brief explanation about your answer and why it should be correct? Thanks!

Comment: Based on 'theme' values in variable DATA (as keys) FlatList renderItem prop is conditionally accepting different Views/Components returned by separate functions.

Comment: Very good! Can you add everything you wrote in the comment, directly in the answer by editing it? That would be how things are usually done here in SO. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
                renderItem={({ item }) => ( 
                  item.isDeleted == false ?  
                  <View>
                       <Activity isRunning={item.isRunning} />
                    </View>
                     : null
                )}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
              />
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking to return two different template sets?  Something like:

```
renderItem={({item, index}) => {
    if (index == 0) {
        return <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <Image source={item.image} style={styles.flatList_imageView} resizeMode="contain"/>
                </View>
    }

    return <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Text>{item.key}</Text>
            </View>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you

```
renderItem={({ item, index })=>
    <View>
        {index == 0 ? <Text>Some Text</Text> : <Text>Some Text</Text> }
    </View>
}}
```